# Take different names from the same column using two different ID's from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I'v got this tables in mySQL database:

**Orders**:

```
Order_ID   ID_employee   ID_Manager
-----------------------------------

123            345           678
234            678           333
146            222           679
```

**personal_info**

```
Person_ID      name    
----------------------

345            Mickey        
333            Mike          
222            Jack
```

I want to get from each table the Order_ID and the names of the employee and his manager.
How can i do that? i tried to write a query using INNER JOIN, but failed to understand how to 
take it from both tables, i also tried to do a sub-query, with no success.

Comment: *i tried to write a query using INNER JOIN, but failed to understand how to take it from both tables* You have 2 indepentent fields in main table - so you must use 2 independent copies of slave table and get data for each separate field from separate table copy.

Comment: How is it you do not have person_id for 678 and 679 and what do you want to do if you don't

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `orders` to 2 copies of `personal_info`, the 1st to get the employee's name and the 2nd to get the manager's name:

```
select o.order_id, p1.name employee, p2.name manager
from orders o
inner join personal_info p1 on p1.person_id = o.id_employee
inner join personal_info p2 on p2.person_id = o.id_manager
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working now, the problem was in the second inner join i tried :-)